# What iOS Control can overlay the detail like Toucharcade app

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I have been searching for a UI Control and don't know what its called, which makes it tough to find right? What UI Control in iOS 5 or 6 provides a view overlay that can swipe away?  Kind of the opposite of a slide-out nav view. I am looking at the TouchArcade app as an example, where you tap an item and this slides out an overlay with an article or review. Its also possible to have several overlay's that can swipe to the right for removal.  Is this a custom control?  I know this must be an easy question, I just don't know what its called, and therefore, my terms don't help much in Google.  The closest thing I have found is ShinobiControls Overlays: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobiessentials/

I'd rather just make my own than rely an somebody else's library I have to keep up to date. On the other hand, that one does look pretty good and would save me time.

**Edit:**
Picture of TouchArcade as an example overlay view.
You see how the article is presented over the list view below?  What controls do that in iOS? It also allows multiple overlays as you click further into each item. You dismiss them by swiping them to the right, dragging them out of view.
[image]

Comment: It's not at all obvious what you're talking about. Could you post a picture?

Comment: Picture added in Edit above. Sorry, I should have done that originally. I know I am not using the correct terms here, otherwise you'd know what I mean, and I'd find them in Google.  :)  Can be frustrating self-learning at times. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I think I may have found what I am looking for: https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck I will test when I have time and if it works the way I think it does i will post an answer resoponse.